# How to Undo/Redo/Rollback in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, rollback, undo, redo

I have read the Neo4j Java Developer Reference Document recently, but I didn't see the information about Undo/Redo/Rollback, so I wonder is the Neo4j support these operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

neo4j does not support undo/redo, but it does support [transactions](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#transactions) (so, rollbacks are supported).

See the specific documentation for [Java](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html), [Cypher](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/introduction/transactions/), [the HTTP API](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/), and [Bolt](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/client-applications/).